# Object replacing the preparatory it

Tags: usage

I have encountered B) many times while I have never seen or heard sentences like D).
Are there specific adjectives having to do with this structure like B)?

> A) It is difficult to solve this math problem.

> B) This math problem is difficult to solve. (O)

> C) It is customary to drink champagne after the ceremony.

> D) Champange is customary to drink after the ceremony. (X)

Comment: Do you mean champagne? You wrote champaign

Comment: I think I would express D as *Drinking champagne is customary after the ceremony.*

Comment: Thank you, Genie. Thank you, Jack.